# How to download a Spacy Model on app engine 2nd Generation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, spacy

I want to install Spacy on GAE 2nd Generation (runtime : python 37) and I don't know how to add `python -m spacy download fr` to get the fr model.

Is there a clean way to do it on app engine ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The models are Python packages, but they're not on PyPI. You can specify them via the `requirements.txt` file for App Engine like so:

```
spacy>=2.0.0,<3.0.0
https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-2.0.0/en_core_web_sm-2.0.0.tar.gz#en_core_web_sm
```

See ["Downloading and requiring model dependencies"](https://spacy.io/usage/models#models-download) in the "Models & Languages" section of `spaCy`'s documentation, as well as [the list of available models](https://spacy.io/usage/models#available).

Comment: However when I am using this method the loading of spacy model `fr_core_news_sm.load()` needs a huge memory amount (`Exceeded soft memory limit of 512 MB with 724 MB after servicing 1 requests total`). Is that normal or is there a way to make it lighter ?

Comment: You'll need to increase your instance size to be able to load the model into memory.